# Access Exchange Using Powershell in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

Im trying to access the exchange server using powershell in c#
Here is the code i am trying to use

```
            WSManConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(@"http://myexchangeserver.com"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", (PSCredential)null);
            ConnectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ConnectionInfo))
            {
                using (PowerShell PS_Instance = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    PS_Instance.AddCommand("Get-MailboxPermission -Identity UAT_TestGeneric");

                    runspace.Open();
                    PS_Instance.Runspace = runspace;
                    Collection<PSObject> results = PS_Instance.Invoke();

                    if (PS_Instance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //Couldnt Connect To Server
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Do Stuff
                    }
                }
```

i keep getting this error message

> The WinRM client received an HTTP status code of 403 from the remote
>   WS-Management service. For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I have checked the exchange servers powershell IIS folder and it doesnt require SSL as indicated here https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/2276957.

Is there any one out there that can assist?
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to try just connecting using Powershell first to test you have the correct prereqs and also check what Auth is correct etc https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297932(v=exchg.141).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As an error 403 means nothing else as "access denied" I think that remote powershell isn´t enabled for the taskuser you are using. Try to enable that via (as written in the MS documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298084(v=exchg.141).aspx)):

```
set-user <your user account> -RemotePowerShellEnabled $True
```

Another useful source to troubleshoot your issue is the MS documentation [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/02/04/troubleshooting-exchange-2010-management-tools-startup-issues/).

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else sees this.
I fixed this because the URI is wrong

```
WSManConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(@"http://myexchangeserver.com"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", (PSCredential)null);
```

The uri needs to be @"http://myexchangeserver.com/Powershell".
So although powershell was setup corretly on the server you need to connect to the correct IIS folder path